# Dynamic html alignment not correct in Chrome but working fine in IE and FF

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code in which I am creating a table using inner Html. The Input box Alignment is good in IE and Firefox but in Chrome it showing up backwards. I don't know what is wrong with this code.

I would appreciate any suggestions you may have.

```
function insertRow(){    

    var pricingType = window.dialogArguments.getAttribute('pricingType');    
      var srcTable = document.getElementById("priceTable"); 
      var tmpRow = null;
      var tmpCell = null;

      var inp1 =  document.createElement("INPUT");
      var inp2 =  document.createElement("INPUT");
      var inp3 =  document.createElement("INPUT");
      var inp4 =  document.createElement("INPUT");
      var inp5 =  document.createElement("INPUT");

      inp1.setAttribute("type","text");
      inp2.setAttribute("type","text");
      inp3.setAttribute("type","text");
      inp4.setAttribute("type","text");
      inp5.setAttribute("type","text");  

      tmpRow = AppendRow(srcTable);
      tmpRow.setAttribute("borderColor","white");     
      tmpCell = AppendCell(tmpRow);
      tmpCell.innerHTML = "<font color=red>* denotes required fields";
      tmpCell.setAttribute("colSpan","2");      
      tmpCell = null;
      tmpRow = null;

    tmpRow = AppendRow(srcTable);
      tmpRow.setAttribute("borderColor","white");

      tmpCell = AppendCell(tmpRow);
      tmpCell.innerHTML = "<b>*Price Qty";
      tmpCell = null;

      if(pricingType == 'T'){             
            tmpCell = AppendCell(tmpRow);
            tmpCell.innerHTML = "<b>*Tier Price";
            tmpCell = null;
      }
      if(pricingType == 'B'){       
            tmpCell = AppendCell(tmpRow);
            tmpCell.innerHTML = "<b>*Bracket Price";
            tmpCell = null;
      }
      tmpRow = null;

      tmpRow = AppendRow(srcTable);
      tmpRow.setAttribute("borderColor","white");

      tmpCell = AppendCell(tmpRow);             
      tmpCell.appendChild(inp1);    
      inp1.setAttribute("name","priceQty");     
      inp1.setAttribute("id","priceQty");
      inp1.setAttribute("value","");
      tmpCell = null;

      tmpCell = AppendCell(tmpRow);
      tmpCell.appendChild(inp2);    
      inp2.setAttribute("name","price");
      inp2.setAttribute("id","price");
      inp2.setAttribute("value","");
      tmpCell = null;
      tmpRow = null;

      tmpRow = AppendRow(srcTable);
      tmpRow.setAttribute("borderColor","white");

      tmpCell = AppendCell(tmpRow);
      tmpCell.innerHTML = "<b>*PriceStartDate(e.g. 06/12/2007)";
      tmpCell = null;

      tmpCell = AppendCell(tmpRow);
      tmpCell.innerHTML = "<b>PriceEndDate(e.g. 06/12/2007)";
      tmpCell = null;   
      tmpRow = null;

      tmpRow = AppendRow(srcTable);
      tmpRow.setAttribute("borderColor","white");     

      tmpCell = AppendCell(tmpRow);
      tmpCell.appendChild(inp3);    
      inp3.setAttribute("name","priceStartDate");
      inp3.setAttribute("id","priceStartDate");
      inp3.setAttribute("value","");
      tmpCell = null;

      tmpCell = AppendCell(tmpRow);
      tmpCell.appendChild(inp4);    
      inp4.setAttribute("name","priceEndDate");
      inp4.setAttribute("id","priceEndDate");
      inp4.setAttribute("value","");
      tmpCell = null;
      tmpRow = null;

      tmpRow = AppendRow(srcTable);
      tmpRow.setAttribute("borderColor","white");

      tmpCell = AppendCell(tmpRow);
      tmpCell.innerHTML = "<b>*Created By";
      tmpCell = null;
      tmpRow = null;

      tmpRow = AppendRow(srcTable);
      tmpRow.setAttribute("borderColor","white");

      tmpCell = AppendCell(tmpRow);             
      tmpCell.appendChild(inp5);    
      inp5.setAttribute("name","createUserId"); 
      inp5.setAttribute("id","createUserId");
      inp5.setAttribute("value","");
      tmpCell = null;
      tmpRow = null;

}

//AppendRow JS funcation

function AppendRow(srcTable)
{
    if(srcTable != null)
    {
        return srcTable.insertRow();
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Error while creating table. Cause: Container Table is null!");
    }
}

//AppendCell JS funcation
function AppendCell(srcRow)
{
    if(srcRow != null)
    {
        return srcRow.insertCell();
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Error while creating table. Cause: Container row is null!");
    }
}
```

Does Chrome has some issue with inner html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `AppendRow()` return the newly created row like this: `return srcTable.insertRow(-1);`

Browsers position the inserted rows differently, if the [index argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.insertRow) is omitted. Passing `-1` appends the newly created row always at the end of the table.